# An alternative method of evaluating a particular limit

Tags: calculus

I want to evaluate the following limit:

> $$\lim_{x\to 1^{+}} \frac{\ln(x)}{x-1}$$

After some thought, I was able to recognize this as the derivative of $\ln(x)$ evaluated at $x=1$ yielding $1$ as the value of the limit.

I would like to know other methods of evaluating this limit.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try write $ln$ as a series?

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned that I'm a beginning calculus student. However, I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: One can compare the slopes of two functions(Which is indirectly L'Hospital's rule).

Comment: Your method is good. I guess you have not yet reached L'Hospital's Rule. Nor have you reached series, but if you make the substitution $x=1+t$ you are looking at the limit as $t$ approaches $0$ of $\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}$ and then you can expand $\ln(1+t)$ in a power series.

Comment: You can use L'hopital's rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that
$$ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}x^n=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots$$
for $|x|\leq1$, unless $x=-1$.

Hence,

$$\begin{matrix}\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{ln(x)}{x-1}&=&\lim_{x\to1+}\frac{(x-1)-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\cdots}{x-1}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to1+}\left(1-\frac{x-1}{2}+\frac{(x-1)^2}{3}-\cdots\right)\\
&=&1\end{matrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

I tried to substitute a simple parameter, given that $\mathcal{D}:(\,0\,;1)\cup(1;+\infty)$:
$$
\ln (x)=z\to x=e^z
$$
then the fundamental limit is shown:
$$
\lim_{x\to 1^+}z=0^+\to\lim_{z\to 0^+}\frac{z}{e^z-1}=\left(\lim_{z\to 0^+}\frac{e^z-1}{z}\right)^{-1}=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x-1=h$ where $h\to 0^+$. Transforming the limit in terms of $h$, you get

$$\lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{\ln(1+h)}{h}$$

You get the limit in the form of a fundamental limit, which equates to $1$.